# User control Dependency property is not getting updated

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, livecharts

I have created a usercontrol for livechart and trying to create dependency properties around it. But the dependency property is not getting updated. I googled and found a [answer in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182165/dependency-property-is-not-updating-my-usercontrol). so I have been searching around. i followed the steps as mentioned in the answer still i am not able to get the chart updated.
CODE:-

```
<LiveChart:CartesianChart Grid.Row="1" Background="White">
        <LiveChart:CartesianChart.AxisX>
            <LiveChart:Axis Title="{Binding Path=XAxisTitle, ElementName=chartControl, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Labels="{Binding Path=XAxisValues, ElementName=chartControl, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </LiveChart:CartesianChart.AxisX>
        <LiveChart:CartesianChart.AxisY>
            <LiveChart:Axis Title="{Binding Path=YAxisTitle, ElementName=chartControl, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" LabelFormatter="{Binding Path=Formatter, ElementName=chartControl, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinValue="0"></LiveChart:Axis>
        </LiveChart:CartesianChart.AxisY>
        <LiveChart:CartesianChart.Series>
            <LiveChart:LineSeries Values="{Binding Path=SpectrumChartSeries, ElementName=chartControl, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"></LiveChart:LineSeries>
        </LiveChart:CartesianChart.Series>
    </LiveChart:CartesianChart>
```

I have named the user control as chartControl and used the ElementName. 
My backend:-

```
public List<Point> ChartPoints
    {
        get { return (List<Point>)GetValue(ChartPointsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ChartPointsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ChartPointsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ChartPoints", typeof(List<Point>), typeof(chartcontrol), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new List<Point>(), onChartrPointChange));

    private static void onChartrPointChange(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = d as chartcontrol;
        var points = e.NewValue as List<Point>;
        control.UpdateChart(points);
    }

    private void UpdateChart(List<Point> chartPoints)
    {
        SpectrumChartSeries = new ChartValues<double>();// { 4, 6, 5, 2, 4, 8, 9, 10, 20, 11, 15 };
        SpectrumChartSeries.AddRange(chartPoints.Select(x => x.Y));
        XAxisValues = chartPoints.Select(x => x.X.ToString()).ToList();//new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
        Formatter = value => (value).ToString("N", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        XAxisTitle = " test title";
        YAxisTitle = "y title";
    }
```

The changed event is getting hit and the values are updated. but still not reflecting in the chart. so bit confused.

The thing is when i try to Use the [WPF tool Snoop](http://www.cplotts.com/2017/10/27/snoop-2-8-0-download/) and click on the line series, i can see that the chart get updated immediately,

Before click:-
[image: Before click]

After click:-
[image: After click]

Comment: In UpdateChart you're updating some (internal?) properties (like SpectrumChartSeries etc). Do these properties notify about changes? As a note, it's certainly not necessary to set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on their Bindings, because the Bindings aren't TwoWay.

Comment: It is written in xaml.cs file so i have not written any notify changes event. should I? as it is code behind. it must update immediately right.

Comment: A Binding like `{Binding Path=SpectrumChartSeries, ...}` only updates its target property when the source property fires a change notification. So SpectrumChartSeries must either be a dependency property or its owning class must implement INotifyPropertyChanged and fire the PropertyChanged event in the SpectrumChartSeries setter.

Comment: @Clemens I tried adding the INotifyPropertyChanged. still does not work. the propertychanged was not getting hit, googled and found to set datacontext. did that also. still not working. any other approach please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the answer so that it might help someone like me.
I was able to find the answer [this blog](https://www.nikolalukovic.com/programming/wpf-custom-usercontrol-datacontext-binding-gotcha) helped me. as they have mentioned i needed to add the datacontext in the Xaml.

```
LiveChart:CartesianChart Grid.Row="1" Background="White" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:LiveChartControl}}">
        <LiveChart:CartesianChart.AxisX>
            <LiveChart:Axis Title="{Binding Path=XAxisTitle, Mode=TwoWay}" Labels="{Binding Path=XAxisValues, Mode=TwoWay}" MinValue="0"/>
        </LiveChart:CartesianChart.AxisX>
        <LiveChart:CartesianChart.AxisY>
            <LiveChart:Axis Title="{Binding Path=YAxisTitle, Mode=TwoWay}" LabelFormatter="{Binding Path=Formatter, Mode=TwoWay}" MinValue="0"></LiveChart:Axis>
        </LiveChart:CartesianChart.AxisY>
        <LiveChart:CartesianChart.Series>
            <LiveChart:LineSeries Values="{Binding Path=ChartPointsInChartValues, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <LiveChart:VerticalLineSeries Values="{Binding Path=EnergyLineChartValues , Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </LiveChart:CartesianChart.Series>
    </LiveChart:CartesianChart>
```

This started to work now.